# Moderator Election Page comments overflow on Mobile version

Tags: bug, design, election

I know that the [Moderator Election](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/3) pages do not have a [mobile version by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120962/no-mobile-site-for-the-election) but when viewing the DBA.SE election page the comments overflow beyond the column for each nominee which does not happen on the Stack Overflow election page.

**DBA.SE Mod Election page on iPhone:**

> [image]

**Stack Overflow Mod Election page:**

> [image]

If the reason for this behavior is because of the comment with the long string of `.........` then shouldn't the comments wrap instead of overflowing as it is?

Comment: Do we have in our midst the possibility of something proposed on meta getting fixed????

Comment: This is actually a longstanding bug on meta if I recall correctly, where some post elements force the post to be wider, so there's a hidden scroll.

Comment: I think, but don't quote me

Comment: @jcolebrand I looked but couldn't find it on meta. Maybe my searching skills are lacking today.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow

Comment: Jon I don't think that's for mobile. bluefeet I know, I don't remember where it's reported. We should ping the shit out of Tim Stone and ask him, since he knows all things client on the stacks ;-)